# How Can I Create Password Field In Sharepoint 2010

Tags: types, sharepoint-2010, textfield

i had a problem with sharepoint data Types.

when i create a single line text column, type of this column is text and when i want use this column as password field, There is no option change type to password.

and characters shown normal Instead of '*****'

i also use infopath, But my problem is not solved

please say me how can i change this text Type to Password in sharepoint forms.

### Type = text

### | 123456451256 |

### Type = Password

### | ************** |